# Does golang rand() use libc rand()

Tags: c, go, random

I use same seed in golang and C,but get different rand number
I know php use libc rand(),how about golang?

```
//golang:
rand.Seed(12345); 
rand.Uint32();

//C:
srand(12345); 
rand();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the [rand](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/) package doesn't use the C standard library at all, which you can tell by looking at each source file to see that it doesn't use CGO.

- [exp.go](https://golang.org/src/math/rand/exp.go):

  ```
  import (
      "math"
  )
  ```
- [normal.go](https://golang.org/src/math/rand/normal.go)

  ```
  import (
      "math"
  )
  ```
- [rand.go](https://golang.org/src/math/rand/rand.go)

  ```
  import "sync"
  ```
- [rng.go](https://golang.org/src/math/rand/rng.go)

  No imports
- [zipf.go](https://golang.org/src/math/rand/zipf.go):

  ```
  import "math"
  ```

Comment: thanks,It seems that i need to use cgo in my go code

Comment: If it's important that you generate random numbers with libc, yes. But I can't imagine why that would be important. :)

Comment: beacase I am using golang to rebuild some php code. php code uses srand() and rand() to do some math calculation,i need to ensure get same result in golang code.

Comment: Then you should write your own implementation that matches your expectation--no need to use CGO.

Comment: of course. now, I am trying to use golang to implement libc rand() .

Answer (score 3):

The C standard imposes limited requirements on the behaviour of `rand()` - what you typically get is a linear congruential generator with a reasonable periodicity (related to `RAND_MAX`) and `srand` allows you to *seed* that generator.

So there's no reason why it would return the same series as another linear congruential generator or otherwise, even with the same starting seed.

If you want your inter-language generators to match, then you might want to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

> Does golang rand() use libc rand()

No.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented function rand and srand by golang.
It can get same result compared to PHP/C.

```
package fcrypt

var index int
var r []int

func mysrand(seed int) {
    r = append(r, seed)
    for i := 1; i < 31; i++ {
        r = append(r, (16807*r[i-1])%2147483647)
        if r[i] < 0 {
            r[i] = r[i] + 2147483647
        }
    }
    for i := 31; i < 34; i++ {
        r = append(r, r[i-31])
    }
    for i := 34; i < 344; i++ {
        r = append(r, r[i-31]+r[i-3])
    }
}
func myrand() uint32 {
    i := 344 + index
    r = append(r, r[i-31]+r[i-3])
    index = index + 1
    return uint32(r[i]) >> 1
}
```

Comment: One serious problem with this code is that its memory usage grows each time `myrand` is called. You should be using a circular buffer of size 32 for `r`. The go stdlib rand uses a similar (not identical) algorithm, which you could copy: https://golang.org/src/math/rand/rng.go

Comment: Also, I think (but am not 100% sure) that it gives different results depending on whether `int` is 32 or 64 bits. You should probably use `int32` or `int64` for elements of `r`.